# What would be the maximum frequency that can be achieved with an LC Oscillator?

Tags: rf, oscillator, frequency, crystal, high-frequency

What would be the maximum frequency that can be achieved with an Oscillator that is based only on Capacitors and Inductors ?
Could it even reach high frequencies like Gigahertz or even Teraherz or are these speeds only achievable using Crystal oscillators ?

Another form of my question would  be "Can LC oscillators reach speeds as high as Crystal oscillators, and if not , why ?"

Comment: That sort of depends on what you consider a "capacitor" or "inductor" to be.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Discrete components ?

Comment: Do they have to be two distinct somethings soldered to the board, and not just geometry on it? What about internal parasitics of the active device itself?  Ultimately, what is your goal?  To set a world record in terms of some definition?  Or to do something useful?  If not the latter, the question doesn't belong here, but if the latter, it is insufficiently specified to be answerable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton i think i am mainly interested in something that can be soldered, but other forms are also interesting

Comment: @ChrisStratton I started wondering about this question when i thought about propagation delay and parasitic capacitance, EMF and other limitations. and since there are many electrical engineers here, i thought many of them might have tackled these issues.

Comment: @ChrisStratton And  "To set a world record in terms of some definition"  would still be a valid question to someone that wants to know the maximum speed that can be achieved with the limitations of such oscillator.

Comment: I've built 1.5GHz oscillators using striplines over planes, with a tuning cap at one end (not sure if "end" matters). The stripline will appear inductive due to phaseshift.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Sounds interesting, do you have any reference url to share?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more a question of what you consider constitutes a capacitor or inductor.

Consider a low frequency LC resonator L1 C1. Assume an active device is coupled into it somehow to sustain oscillation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC904z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To increase the frequency, reduce the value of C1, reduce the value of L1.

Eventually by the time we get to resonator 2, L2 has become a single straight piece of wire. The L2 now has a large component that is the leads of C2, so we need to make it leadless. Let's reduce the dielectric constant down to unity, by removing all the plastic/ceramic from inside, and make it with air-spaced plates. We can reduce the capacitance further by separating the plates.

In resonator 3, we reduce the inductance further by using several in parallel. Each inductor becomes a wide ribbon, instead of a wire. In 3 dimensions, we would arrange several of these round the central capacitor so they formed a continuous cylindrical wall.

In resonator 4, we are employing the stray capacitance between the top and the bottom of the inductors as our resonating capacitance, so there is no need for an additional physical component for C4. You can treat this resonator equivalently as L and C components, or as waveguide modes, both give the same answer.

I've not drawn resonator 5, where the gap between the plates of C5 has increased to where the resonator is now a simple rectangular box. As you continue to shrink the size of the box smaller and smaller, the resonant frequency continues to increase. You can treat this resonator equivalently as L and C components, or waveguide modes, or as photons trapped in a box, all three give the same answer.

Comment: so a single wire could be an inductor without any turns in it  or is it just a symbol?

Comment: @soundslikefiziks any wire has inductance, search for appropriate calculators. This inductance is usually only apparent at higher frequencies, as it's small (nH levels).

Comment: @soundslikefiziks A single wire does have inductance. For 'typical' sub-mm wire sizes, 1nH per mm is a reasonable ballpark. That's what RF engineers use for an order-of-magnitude estimate for the effects of additional lengths of bond wires, thin tracks, traces within components.