# Can a LC circuit generate frequencies in the Gigahertz range or higher?

Tags: radio, capacitance, inductance, resonance, radiation

For instance, if you took a bunch of off the shelf capacitors and arranged them in series and a bunch of inductors and arranged them in parallel, could you make the resonant frequency of the LC circuit high enough to be in the Gigahertz range or higher? Maybe even Gamma radiation range?

Comment: No, absolutely not.

Comment: Do you know how traces are measured in nH/mm ? have you calculated impedances of root(L/C) and resonace of omega=1/root(LC) yet? Do you know how to calculate Q and loss tangent of dielectrics? If not then keep studying RF design

Comment: User, [here's what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK801.png) when you just tiptoe into GHz areas (low decimeters.) And gamma is down into picometers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off-the-shelf chip capacitors are available in fractional pF values, and inductors in low nH, or use trace inductances to the same effect.  This gives a lumped equivalent circuit in the low GHz just fine.

You don't even need components, the trace area (capacitance) and length (inductance) on a PCB have equivalent effect; this serves up to low 100s GHz (special fine-feature PCBs) to low THz (integrated circuits with ~µm features).

But such networks do not "generate" frequencies, they simply have a characteristic.  No energy is put into that characteristic, by itself.  You need an oscillator to generate that.  Which is quite challenging as you go up in frequency (usually using fancy amplifier designs in ICs, combined with those same "LC" networks).

Answer (score 1):

In theory, maybe... But in practice certainly not.

Real capacitors and inductors do not behave ideally, especially at high frequencies. The parasitics alone are likely to prevent you from reaching multiple gigahertz. Adding additional components adds additional parasitic inductance and capacitance which will substract from your resonant frequency. At a certain point I would not be surprised if adding additional components actually *decreased* your resonant frequency.

There are other non-idealities at play here. For example, ceramic capacitors do not even behave as capacitors after a few hundred megahertz due to package inductance. Leaded capacitors are even worse, of course...

EDIT: Another answer makes good points about chip scale features and using PCB features to create resonant circuits. I am assuming the OP is talking about discrete components only.

For another take on this question, see [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367567/what-would-be-the-maximum-frequency-that-can-be-achieved-with-an-lc-oscillator)